# unable to install ebaytd package

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the package ebaytd in r but unable to do so in R 4.0.2 and previous versions. I also tried installing it in rdevel for 4.1.0 but it's showing me the error that it is not available (for R Under development);
I tried to install using this code;
`install.packages('ebaytd_1.10.tar', lib='E://')` but it's giving me the error;

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘ebaytd_1.10.tar’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)

This is the download link of my package;
https://filebin.net/t9ngvjoasnzcawdp

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid R package? I can't find any reference about it elsewhere.

Comment: do you mean this is the package you re trying to install? https://github.com/mattwg/course-ebaytd